# Ignore multiple button taps after first one on iPhone webapp using jQuery Mobile?

Tags: iphone, ios, html, jquery-mobile

Assume button A in an HTML5 webapp built with jQuery Mobile.

If someone taps button A, we call foo(). Foo() should get called once even if the user double taps button A.

We tried using event.preventDefault(), but that didn't stop the second tap from invoking foo(). event.stopImmediatePropagation() might work, but it also stops other methods further up the stack and may not lead to clean code maintenance.

Other suggestions? Maintaining a tracking variable seems like an awfully ugly solution and is undesirable.

Answer (score 1):

You can set a flag and check if it's OK to run the `foo()` function or unbind the event for the time you don't want the user to be able to use it and then re-bind the event handler after a delay (just a couple options).

Here's what I would do. I would use a timeout to exclude the subsequent events:

```
$(document).delegate('#my-page-id', 'pageinit', function () {

    //setup a flag to determine if it's OK to run the event handler
    var okFlag = true;

    //bind event handler to the element in question for the `click` event
    $('#my-button-id').bind('click', function () {

        //check to see if the flag is set to `true`, do nothing if it's not
        if (okFlag) {

            //set the flag to `false` so the event handler will be disabled until the timeout resolves
            okFlag = false;

            //set a timeout to set the flag back to `true` which enables the event handler once again
            //you can change the delay for the timeout to whatever you may need, note that units are in milliseconds
            setTimeout(function () {
                okFlag = true; 
            }, 300);

            //and now, finally, run your original event handler
            foo();
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: I know the original question mentioned not using a tracking variable, however, after 3 hours of googling and trial-and-error, this works a treat! +1 from me.

Comment: Yeah, if you're not into a separate variable, you can store the flag variable as jQuery data too. `$.data(this, 'flag', [state])`

Answer (score 0):

I've created a sample here http://jsfiddle.net/kiliman/kH924/

If you're using `<a data-role="button">` type buttons, there is no 'disabled' status, but you can add the appropriate class to give it the disabled look.

In your event handler, check to see if the button has the `ui-disabled` class, and if so, you can return right away. If it doesn't, add the `ui-disabled` class, then call `foo()`

If you want to re-enable the button, simply remove the class.

```
$(function() {
    $('#page').bind('pageinit', function(e, data) {
        // initialize page
        $('#dofoo').click(function() {
            var $btn = $(this),
                isDisabled = $btn.hasClass('ui-disabled');
            if (isDisabled) {
                e.preventDefault();
                return;
            }
            $btn.addClass('ui-disabled');
            foo();
        });
    });

    function foo() {
        alert('I did foo');
    }
});
```